# Login.js is not showing div in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my div is not showing up on the localhost site from my `login.js` file. Am I doing something wrong with the routes or something? I don't know why nothing it is not being shown.
`login.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

const Login = () => {
    return <div>Login</div>;
};

export default Login;
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import './App.css';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Landing/>} />
      </Routes>
      <section className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/Register' element={<Register/>} />
          <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login/>} />
        </Routes>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
);
export default App;
```

Please Help!

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. I was typing in login.html when its just /login in the web browser

Answer (score 0):

It's should work.
I test it and It's working! I don't get any problem.

You can test by do these:

1. Remove 'exact' from each route. In version of router 6 don't need to write 'exact'.
2. Write route path in lowercase. // => "/login"
3. And check your Login component's path properly.

Best of Luck. Happy Coding!